# execution of jQuery statements inside a if block

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, browser

I have a couple of jQuery statements that should be invoked when an event occurs

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {



$("#select_update").on("change", ()=> {
   
 if ( $("#select_update option").eq(1).attr('class') !== 'default1' ) {

        $("#select_update option").eq(1).toggleClass('default2 default1');
       
         $("#which_default").empty().removeClass('default2');  

     }

});
```

when the event fires and the condition is true the last statement gets not executed
while inserting the code into the console of the browser the statements get executed correctly
why so?

Comment: Sounds like the element with the id of `select_update` is not being found when the script runs

Comment: Or the element is being destroyed and recreated after the event is bound, and thus lost

Comment: If the element is created dynamically, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements